# $_FILES is empty using yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework but in this specific situation I didn't use the activeform, so I'm using a normal input file like

```
<form id="formId">
   <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
   <input type="file" name="nameFile" id="nameFile" />
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

in javascript, inside $(document).ready, I have

```
    $("#formId").on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            url: "index.php?r=myControllerAction",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXhr);
            }
        });
});
```

In my controller, the $_FILES is empty. Someone knows why?

Comment: try adding this atrribute: enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form

Answer (score -1):

In your form encryption type is missing :

```
<form id="formId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
   <input type="file" name="nameFile" id="nameFile" />
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```